# Developing very basic windows 8.1 app. How to perform validation from xaml code behind

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-8.1

hi im developing a very simple windows 8.1 desktop app which i want to do user input validation. to force that some fields are input and also to do some conditional validation. im not doing MVVM etc just xaml with code behind.

can someone point me to a blog/ sample which does this very basic functionality properly?

please help

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/), which offers TextBoxValidationExtensions. You can use them like this:

```
<TextBox toolkit:TextBoxValidationExtensions.Format="NonEmptyNumeric"/>
```

It also lets you choose a brush to highlight the textbox when invalid input is entered.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [WinRT XAML Validation](http://winrtxamlvalidation.codeplex.com/) library.